# Aligning parbox vertically in .cls file

Tags: templates, cv, friggeri-cv

I'm using this https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/fancy-cv
template to write my cv. I have faced a very tiny problem in formatting and was hoping to get some hints from folks here.

**The Problem**:

[image]

As you can see,"since 2009 month" became 2 row but instead of aligning with Ph.D. canididate in Computer Science, it decided to insert an extra line above it.

I would like this to change so that "since 2009" aligns with "Ph.D. candidate" line

**Code**:

Here is the *cv.tex* section responsible for the area:

```
\section{education}

\begin{entrylist}
  \entry
    {since 2009\\ month}
    {Ph.D. {\normalfont candidate in Computer Science}}
    {DNET/INRIA, LIP/ÉNS de Lyon}
    {\emph{A Quantified Theory of Social Cohesion.}}
  ...
\end{entrylist}
```

And here is the *friggeri-cv.cls* section:

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{11.8cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
```

**My Attempt**:

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[5]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{11.8cm}
  #5&\parbox[t]{11.8cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
```

---

```
\begin{entrylist}
  \entry
    {since 2009}
    {Ph.D. {\normalfont candidate in Computer Science}}
    {DNET/INRIA, LIP/ÉNS de Lyon}
    {\emph{A Quantified Theory of Social Cohesion.}}
    {month}
```

Unfortunately, it didn't compile well... Please help me understand what went wrong. Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Your code snippet are interesting, however it require additional effort from people, who can help you, that from them make a short document, which will show your problem. Please, help them and prepare Minimal Working Example!

Comment: ^^ This. We need a complete small example which produces the output you show. Guessing: try `\parbox[t]{3cm}{since 2009\\ month}` with the original definition. 3cm is probably wrong, but whatever you figure it should be.

Comment: Do not change the class file!

Answer (score 1):

Use a `\parbox` for `#1` too. Add the following in the preamble.

```
\renewcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  \parbox[t]{0.18\linewidth}{#1\par}&\parbox[t]{0.82\linewidth}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
```

Adjust `0.18\linewidth` and `0.82\linewidth` as you wish.

[image]